# Precision difference between a raycast and OnMouseOver

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm really surprised by what I see in my Unity3D project and was wondering if anyone has an explanation as I didn't find one after looking for it on google.

So I have a project where I instantiate multiples objects, which are basically cubes, with their colliders (not triggered) and where I want to know if the mouse is over one of them.
So I attached a very basic script taken from the unity documentation:

```
void OnMouseEnter()
{
    Debug.Log("enter block " + this.name); 
    // Change the color of the GameObject to red when the mouse is over GameObject
    m_Renderer.material.color = m_MouseOverColor;
}

void OnMouseOver()
{
    Debug.Log("over block " + this.name); 
    // Change the color of the GameObject to red when the mouse is over GameObject
    m_Renderer.material.color = m_MouseOverColor;
}

void OnMouseExit()
{
    Debug.Log("exit block " + this.name);
    // Reset the color of the GameObject back to normal
    m_Renderer.material.color = m_OriginalColor;
}
```

And I don't seem to see any result. While looking for options I scaled the collider box to way bigger and can get some results, but they are not precise, the mouse needs to be slightly on the side of the cubes to work. It looks like a perspective effect caused by hte size of the collider by that would be annoying for the final user.

So I tried to use a simple raycast test in a script attached to the camera:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100000000, LayerMask.GetMask("TrackPartEnd")))
{
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100000000, Color.blue, 3);
    myCursorObject.transform.position = hit.point;
}
else
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100000000, LayerMask.GetMask("Floor")))
    {
       Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100000000, Color.green, 3);
       myCursorObject.transform.position = hit.point;
    }
    else
    {
       Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100000000, Color.red, 3);
    }
}
```

And with this one I get a really good result, it's fast and really precise.

But I didn't find any explanation on why? To my knowledge, OnMouseOver uses raycast as well. I've double-checked and I don't see anything blocking the rays neither.
Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: it seems to be working perfectly well for me. You've got two `OnMouseEnter`s in your script, which would prevent compilation. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, that's a copy paste error for this question, I'll edit it.

Comment: Still, it should work just fine. Create a new cube, place the script with the code on it and see what happens. I've just done that and it works accurately.